# JSLINQ groupBy error

Tags: javascript, jslinq

I am trying to manipulate a json file, so I am trying JSLINQ, but I can't figure out why I hit an error at groupBy().
[The website that led me to this code.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jslinq#make-a-groupby-and-count-on-each-group)

```
var query = JSLINQ(json);
    var result = query.groupBy(function (i) {   //HERE is where the error hits.
            return i.CustomerName;    //Attribute of json
        })
        .select(function (i) {
            console.log(i);
            return {
                CustomerName: i.Key, data: i.elements   //I read that I get groupBy result like this.
                    .select(function (j) {
                        x = j.x, y = j.y      //x and y are attributes
                    })
            }
        }).toArray();
```

> query.groupBy is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask and ye shall receive young padawan ...

```
var result = jslinq(data)
   .groupBy(function (i) { return i.CustomerName; })
   .select(function(g) {
      return {
         key: g.key,
         items: jslinq(g.elements).select(function(i) { return { x: i.x, y: i.y } }).items
      };
    })
    .toList();

console.log(result);
```

....

Key differences between yours and mine ...

- jslinq has been lowered in the version listed on github
- element collections in the groups need to be wrapped in jslinq() too to be queried